# Decimal Precision Issue | Big Decimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

1.

```
    BigDecimal ap = new BigDecimal(170.8999999999998,   MathContext.DECIMAL64).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
```

result : 170.89 (Required : 170.89)

2.

```
    BigDecimal ap = new BigDecimal(170.89999999999998, MathContext.DECIMAL64).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR); (1 Extra 9 in value)
```

result : 170.90 (Required : 170.89)

3.

```
    BigDecimal ap = new BigDecimal(2401.99).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
```

result : 2401.98 (Required : 2401.99)

How to get just 2 digit after decimal from value without rounding.

P.S : I do not want to convert the value to String.

Comment: Put the number in quotes, so that you are passing its string representation to BigDecimal. Currently you are using a double literal, incurring rounding error during compilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2401.99` is a `double` *literal*, with an actual value just below that.

Use the `BigDecimal` constructor from a `String` instead.

Comment: so `2401.99` is actually something like `2401.9888888888888887`, and `170.89999999999998` is actually smth like `170.90000000000000003`

Comment: The closest double to 2401.99 is 2401.989999999999781721271574497222900390625, the closest double to 170.89999999999998 is 170.8999999999999772626324556767940521240234375. Part of the problem is using ROUND_FLOOR, rather than e.g. ROUND_HALF_EVEN, but the real fix is to avoid the conversion to double.

Comment: @P45Imminent Actually I am getting these values as an argument to a function with type double and I am converting it to BigDecimal for doing some financial calculations. I don't want to have precision issue while adding or subtracting from other values. Is there any way to do this without converting it to String ?

Comment: @ABJK What you're doing is already wrong.  If you are doing _any kind_ of financial calculations, your values must _never_ be of `double` type.  Having it go through `double` at _any point_ makes your code broken.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I know, but let's say it's "legacy" issue and I have to handle it at my part.

Comment: -sigh- `BigDecimal.valueOf` will paper over the problem, kind of.  Probably.  It'll more likely conceal small bugs that will go undetected until the worst possible moment.